# How to remove Sheets form Excel sheet using JExcel

Tags: java, jxl

I am trying to remove sheets from an existing excel file  using jxl api.

I cannot use

```
WritableWorkbook wwb = new Workbook.createWorkbook("abc.xls");
```

as I do not want to create a new workbook, rather I want to use an existing one.

I cannot use

```
Workbook wb = new Workbook.getWorkbook("abc.xls");
```

as this would get the file in **read only** mode. There is no "**getWorkbook**" method for the class **WritableWorkbook**. Please tell me how to go about it.

I searched through examples online but in each case a new workbook is being created rather than using an existing one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to edit an existing excel file,you can do like this：

```
//Get the existing excel file
  Workbook file=Workbook.getWorkbook(new File("test.xls"));
//Open a copy of the excel file,and specify the parameters to write the data back
//to the original file.
  WritableWorkbook writeBook=Workbook.createWorkbook(new File("test.xls"),file);
  writeBook.removeSheet(0);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
WritableWorkbook wwb = new Workbook.createWorkbook("abc.xls");
```

This line is wrong. You can't use "new" since the class Workbook is a factory that returns a new Workbook. Try this:

```
WritableWorkbook wwb = Workbook.createWorkbook("abc.xls");
```

Answer (score 0):

Call [removeSheet](http://jexcelapi.sourceforge.net/resources/javadocs/2_6_10/docs/jxl/write/WritableWorkbook.html#removeSheet%28int%29) on the workbook instance?  It's right there in the documentation...

Comment: :- Please See my Comments I Have updated my question. Thanks for responding.

Comment: @nirajdeshmukh I believe you have to make a [copy of the workbook, edit this copy](http://www.andykhan.com/jexcelapi/tutorial.html#copying%20and%20modifying), then finally write the copy over the original